# Recursion: Collatz sequence -Could someone please explain how this code returns the total number of steps?

Tags: c, cs50, collatz

```
#include <cs50.h>

int collatz(int n);

int main(void)
{
    int n = get_int("Enter int: ");
    int steps = collatz(n);
    printf("%i\n", steps);
}

int collatz(int n)
{
    if (n==1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else if ((n%2)==0)
    {
        return 1 + collatz(n/2);
    }

    else
    {
        return 1 + collatz(3 * n + 1);
    }
}
```

I am geting stuck trying to visualise how the 'return 1' on each iteration of the function gets 'carried through'.

I can write the steps out on paper to show that it does work, however I am struggling to make clear in my mind without going through step-by-step, why you have to +1 on every iteration of collatz.

Comment: There is no `return 1`. There is `return 1+ <recursive call>`

Comment: Try proving by induction that the function returns the number of steps. This way you don't need to visualise anything.

Comment: Try understanding a simpler recursion: `int foo(int n) { if (n == 0) return 1; else return 1+foo(n-1); }`

Comment: You should write the code using tail recursion: `int collatz(int n, int s){return n<2 ? s : collatz(n&1 ? n*3+1 : n>>1, s+1);}` easier to understand, easier for a compiler to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
    if (n==1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

says: If there are no steps to perform (because `n` is already 1), return zero.

Otherwise, this code:

```
    else if ((n%2)==0)
```

selects one of the following:

```
        return 1 + collatz(n/2);
```

or:

```
        return 1 + collatz(3 * n + 1);
```

Each of those performs one step (either `n/2` or `3 * n + 1`) and then calls `collatz` to find out how many steps it takes to finish with that value. When `collatz` returns the number of steps needed for `n/2` or `3 * n + 1`, this code adds one for the step performed here. That gives the number of steps needed for `n`, which this code then returns.

Comment: Perfect, I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

Try to visualize it as follows:

starting number: 3

```
** collatz(3): return 1 + collatz(10); **

collatz(10): return 1 + collatz(5);

** collatz(3): return 1 + (1 + collatz(5)); **

collatz(5): return 1 + collatz(16);

** collatz(3): return 1 + (1 + (1 + collatz(16))); **

collatz(16): return 1 + collatz(8);

** collatz(3): return 1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + collatz(8)))); **

collatz(8): return 1 + collatz(4);

** collatz(3): return 1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + collatz(4))))); **

collatz(4): return 1 + collatz(2);

** collatz(3): return 1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + collatz(2)))))); **

collatz(2): return 1 + collatz(1);

collatz(1): return 0;

** collatz(3): return 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0; **
```